How can we employ libp2p to establish a secure private network that is impervious to unauthorized connections?
backgroung
Currently, I am looking to utilize Helia to construct a private IPFS network. The critical issue at hand is "Ensuring that this private network remains inaccessible to external nodes." Since Helia's network layer is implemented using the libp2p package, our security measures will also leverage this libp2p framework.
Question
My inquiry is: How can we employ libp2p to establish a secure private network that is impervious to unauthorized connections? If you possess the expertise to assist me in this matter, I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you could provide here. Thank you in advance for your valuable support!
